# Fast interpolation between a collection of points

Tags: java, performance

I've built a model of the solar system in Java. In order to determine the position of a planet it does do a whole lot of computations which give a very exact value. However I am often satisfied with the approximate position, if that could make it go faster. Because I'm using it in a simulation speed is important, as the position of the planet will be requested millions of times.

Currently I try to cache the position of a planet throughout its orbit and then use those coordinates over and over. If a position in between two values is requested I perform a linear interpolation. This is how I store values:

```
for(int t=0; t<tp; t++) {
    listCoordinates[t]=super.coordinates(ti+t);
}

interpolator = new PlanetOrbit(listCoordinates,tp);
```

`PlanetOrbit` has the interpolation code:

```
package cometsim;

import org.apache.commons.math3.util.FastMath;

public class PlanetOrbit {

    final double[][] coordinates;
    double tp;

    public PlanetOrbit(double[][] coordinates, double tp) {
        this.coordinates = coordinates;
        this.tp = tp;
    }

    public double[] coordinates(double julian) {
        double T = julian % FastMath.floor(tp);

        if(coordinates.length == 1 || coordinates.length == 0) return coordinates[0];

        if(FastMath.round(T) == T) return coordinates[(int) T];

        int floor = (int) FastMath.floor(T);

        if(floor>=coordinates.length) floor=coordinates.length-5;

        double[] f = coordinates[floor];
        double[] c = coordinates[floor+1];

        double[] retval = f;
        retval[0] += (T-FastMath.floor(T))*(c[0]-f[0]);
        retval[1] += (T-FastMath.floor(T))*(c[1]-f[1]);
        retval[2] += (T-FastMath.floor(T))*(c[2]-f[2]);

        return retval;
    }
}
```

You can think of `FastMath` as `Math` but faster. However, this code is not much of a speed improvement over calculating the exact value every time. Do you have any ideas for how to make it faster?

Comment: Is my reading of this correct that the method `coordinates` actually changes the values within field `coordinates`?

Comment: @RichardTingle In the first snippet of code `coordinates` return an array of three values for each `t`, those arrays are stored in `listCoordinates`. `listCoordinates` is given to `PlanetOrbit` in which it is stored. It is never changed from then on, but I use that list to acquire the position. `PlanetOrbit.coordinates` is the method I will call during simulation to find out the position of the planet.

Comment: Ok, I would strongly advise not calling everything `coordinates`. I mean the method PlanetOrbit#coordinates. Within that method `f = coordinates[floor];` then `double[] retval = f;` then `retval` is modified

Comment: However; an optimation I can see is that you floor T 3 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues I can see, the main ones I can see are as follows

- `PlanetOrbit#coordinates` seems to actually change the values in the variable `coordinates`. As this method is supposed to only interpolate I expect that your orbit will actually corrupt slightly everytime you run though it (because it is a linear interpolation the orbit will actually degrade towards its centre).
- You do the same thing several times, most clearly `T-FastMath.floor(T)` occures 3 seperate times in the code.
- Not a question of efficiency or accuracy but the variable and method names are very opaque, use real words for variable names.

My proposed method would be as follows

```
public double[] getInterpolatedCoordinates(double julian){ //julian calendar? This variable name needs to be something else, like day, or time, or whatever it actually means
    int startIndex=(int)julian;
    int endIndex=(startIndex+1>=coordinates.length?1:startIndex+1); //wrap around

    double nonIntegerPortion=julian-startIndex;


    double[] start = coordinates[startIndex];
    double[] end = coordinates[endIndex];

    double[] returnPosition= new double[3];

    for(int i=0;i< start.length;i++){
        returnPosition[i]=start[i]*(1-nonIntegerPortion)+end[i]*nonIntegerPortion;
    }
    return returnPosition;
}
```

This avoids corrupting the coordinates array and avoids repeating the same floor several times (`1-nonIntegerPortion` is still done several times and could be removed if needs be but I expect profiling will show it isn't significant). However, it does create a new double[] each time which may be inefficient if you only need the array temporarily. This can be corrected using a store object (an object you used previously but no longer need, usually from the previous loop)

```
public double[] getInterpolatedCoordinates(double julian, double[] store){
    int startIndex=(int)julian;
    int endIndex=(startIndex+1>=coordinates.length?1:startIndex+1); //wrap around

    double nonIntegerPortion=julian-startIndex;


    double[] start = coordinates[startIndex];
    double[] end = coordinates[endIndex];

    double[] returnPosition= store;

    for(int i=0;i< start.length;i++){
        returnPosition[i]=start[i]*(1-nonIntegerPortion)+end[i]*nonIntegerPortion;
    }
    return returnPosition; //store is returned
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer is great and very helpful. I like the trick with `store`, I hadn't seen that before.